# Why is there a runtime assert for "Expression: cannot decrement deque iterator before begin" in VC++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, iterator, language-lawyer, deque

```
void foo (std::deque<Class>& dq)
{
  auto it = dq.begin();
  --it;  // <--- asserts in VC++
  ...
}
```

Above code is an oversimplified version, but similar is happening in my code. It works fine in Ubuntu/Linux, but asserts and aborts the program with Visual studio.

> Expression: **cannot decrement deque iterator before begin**
>
> For information on how your program can cause assertion failure, see VC++ ...

Even though we are not seeking or dereferencing the value of the iterator, why does it treats it as a runtime error?

Comment: But does it make any sense? I think it's correct that the code assert

Comment: `--dq.begin()` is UB, anything can happen. VC++ warns you about your mistake (at least in some configuration).

Comment: It's Undefined Behaviour. Compiler is allowed to hold your hand and prevent you from making errors, but is not required to.

Comment: How would you implement this operation on something that's usually implemented using a doubly linked list?

Comment: You're trying to move outside your data structure. There is nothing before begin(), you would end up in memory not belonging to your datastructure which would leave your program in a unsafe state. That it seems to work on linux isn't a guarantee that your code is correct.

Comment: This is sticking to the spirit of the undefined-ness of `int x; int *p = &x; --p;`.

Answer (score 5):

From the description of the named requirement [LegacyBidirectionalIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator):

> The begin iterator is not decrementable and the behavior is undefined if `--container.begin()` is evaluated.

Note that behavior isn't undefined only if `--container.begin()` is dereferenced. Simply attempting to decrement the begin iterator at all is undefined behavior.

From the [standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/bidirectional.iterators) on bidirectional iterators, the following precondition applies to `--r` when `r` is a bidirectional iterator:

> *Preconditions:* there exists `s` such that `r == ++s`.

There is no such `s` for `dq.begin()` and so decrementing it is undefined behavior.

Comment: @iammilind https://eel.is/c++draft/bidirectional.iterators. For the future, if you want answers to reference standard, add [tag:language-lawyer] tag to your question

Comment: That tag is now added. I couldn't find the exact quote from the link you posted. Plz add the relevant reference in your answer.

Comment: I did. It's a precondition for the validity of the decrement operation.